# Perl encoding from JSON issue

Tags: json, perl, unicode

apologies if this is a really stupid question or already asked elsewhere. I'm reading in some JSON and using decode_json on it, then extracting text from it and outputting that to a file.

My problem is that Unicode characters are encoded as eg \u2019 in the JSON, decode_json appears to convert this to \x{2019}. When I grab this text and output to a UTF8-encoded file, it appears as garbage.

Sample code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;

open IN, $file or die;
binmode IN, ":utf8";
my $data = <IN>;
my $json = decode_json( $data );
open OUT, ">$outfile" or die;
binmode OUT, ":utf8";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
foreach my $textdat (@{ $json->{'results'} }) {
    print STDOUT Dumper($textdat);
    my $text = $textdat->{'text'};
    print OUT "$text\n";
}
```

The Dumper output shows that the \u encoding has been converted to \x encoding. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`decode_json` needs UTF-8 encoded input, so use `from_json` instead that accepts unicode:

```
my $json = from_json($data);
```

Another option would be to encode the data yourself:

```
use Encode;

my $encoded_data = encode('UTF-8', $data);
...
my $json = decode_json($data);
```

But it makes little sense to encode data just to decode it.

Comment: The first option didn't fix it, but from_json did - thank you!

Comment: @DomGlennon: Oh, I forgot to include `use Encode`, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`decode_json` expects UTF-8, but you're passing decoded text (Unicode Code Points) instead.

So, you could remove the existing character decoding.

```
use feature qw( say );
use open 'std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use JSON qw( decode_json );

my $json_utf8 = do {
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $in_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");

   local $/;
   <$fh>;
 };

my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);

{
   open(my $fh, '>', $out_qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

   for my $result (@{ $data->{results} }) {
      say $fh $result->{text};
   }
}
```

Or, you could use `from_json` (or `JSON->new->decode`) instead of `decode_json`.

```
use feature qw( say );
use open 'std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use JSON qw( from_json );                         # <---

my $json_ucp = do {
   open(my $fh, '<', $in_qfn)                     # <---
      or die("Can't open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");

   local $/;
   <$fh>;
 };

my $data = from_json($json_ucp);                  # <---

{
   open(my $fh, '>', $out_qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

   for my $result (@{ $data->{results} }) {
      say $fh $result->{text};
   }
}
```

The arrows point to the three minor differences between the two snippets.

---

I made a number of cleanups.

- Missing `local $/;` in case there are line breaks in the JSON.
- Don't use 2-arg `open`.
- Don't needlessly use global variables.
- Use better names for variables. `$data` and `$json` were notably reversed, and `$file` didn't contain a file.
- Limit the scope of your variables, especially if they use up system resources (e.g. file handles).
- Use `:encoding(UTF-8)` (the standard encoding) instead of `:encoding(utf8)` (an encoding only used by Perl). `:utf8` is even worse as it uses the internal encoding rather than the standard one, and it can lead to corrupt scalars if provided bad input.
- Get rid of the noisy quotes around identifiers used as hash keys.